# Save scroll position before destroy

Tags: angular

I would like to save the scroll position before my component is destroyed.

I thought I could save it in `ngOnDestroy()` but when I check the `scrollTop` or `scrollY` properties, they are equal to 0. Please note that both properties are equal to the right number when I check with a button... I conclude that when trying to get it in `ngOnDestroy()` it's already too late.

Any suggestion how to do it (ideally saving it once)?

(Using Angular 2 RC5)

Edit:

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OCdhEonzrkpRaT8iYB0i?p=preview) to illustrate the problem. Check the console for the scroll position

[I created an Angular2 issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11003)

Comment: Do you mean `ngOnDestroy()`? Actually I think DOM element should be still here at that moment, because this hook is made to remove event listeners. Could you give the code?

Comment: @FriOne Well, the code is just console.log(window.scrollY); inside ngOnDestroy after scrolling... (and yes it's ngOnDestroy and not NgOnDestroy, thanks for pointing that out...)

Comment: So after view element init you have different scrollY value? Does your component inside ngFor with oher elements? And you don't have overflow hidden anywhere? It is hard to help you without code.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you tried. What about saving the value on each scroll event and not only in `ngOnDestroy`?

Comment: @FriOne Please see the plunker I've just added

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Please see the plunker I've just added

Comment: How can I reproduce (make `ngOnDestroy()`) being called?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Did you check the plunker? Everything is in the home.component.ts

Comment: Yes, but what do I have to do in order to see the effect? The component doesn't seem to get destroyed at any time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121607/discussion-between-ncohen-and-gunter-zochbauer).